# How can I merge multiple revisions of notes together into a single version?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, algorithm, mongoose, synchronization

Forgive me if this question has been asked before. I'm sure it has since a classic problem. But nevertheless, I will ask it since I couldn't locate a solution.

- I have a mongo/mongoose/node stack API for a note taking application.
- Users of the app can open it up in different devices or browser tabs and sometimes end up overriding their own notes.

Here is a time-linear example of a single user with different mediums which encounters the problem:

1. User opens app in phone (offline)
2. Later, User opens the app
   in browser and edits a specific note.
3. User goes back to app in phone and edits same note. Now the phone app. overrides the edits made in #2 because phone was "out of sync".

There are two main problems:
1. The app does not initiate a sync. It remains out of sync unless the user manually clicks refresh.
2. Merging of the two notes is difficult because it's not as simple as the last one being the authoritative one but rather, I think that it needs to merge the two together elegantly (think github diff)

What is a known strategy for handling such problem? My initial research points to something like jsdiff which highlights differences but it does not take into account syncing and revision resolution with mongoose.

TLDR;
I got multiple notes. I need to merge them. They may vary.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [jsondiffpatch](https://github.com/benjamine/jsondiffpatch) if you haven't already.

Comment: Are you looking for a library that can do that or a general strategy for implementing yourself?

Comment: I'm looking for a general strategy of implementation and/or library if you know of some

Comment: Why not use Git?

Comment: The git diff is great but I'm not sure how this will be integrated with my app. ideas?

Comment: you need set time follow of versions, and implement a strategic priority replace/delete/crete section note

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to deal with a similar issue in the past (syncing offline events).
Here what we did in general, hope it would help.

> 1. The app does not initiate a sync

You want to minimize the timeframe where sync issues can rise.

This can be solved by triggering sync observing the state of [navigator.online](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/Online_and_offline_events#navigator.onLine).
1. when it changes to false, start buffering the user edits.
2. when it changes to true, pull the new changes from the server, then push buffered actions.

> 2. Merging of the two notes...

This can be quite challenging. It really depends on the type of data, and how tolerant are you to sync errors.

We found that its best to handle sync issues as close to the source as possible. We contained the sync issues at the client side, so corrupted data would never reach the DB.

The sync itself behaves like a git merge.

When the offline device pulls the updated data, it would attempt to merge the buffered actions **before** sending it to the server.

- if a conflict is detected, it would try to auto-correct it. adding timestamps to every action may help to sort the order of actions from multiple devices.
- if auto correction fails, it would prompt the user to resolve it manually.

I Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What kind of diff algorithm you use to resolve the conflicts?

Comment: At our case we didn't diff contnent (we synced workers reported work hours), so it may not fit your needs. When we find a conflic (the worker reported overlapping work sessions), we display them both to the user, and he needs to fix edit them to it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Well basically there is no magic solution for this problem. This is very common problem and solution depend on business requirements, first of all I suggest you to read [Designing Data-Intensive Applications](https://dataintensive.net/)
, this book explain exactly those kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem, especially for mobile environments. An interesting approach is to use Service Workers in a Progressive Web App. These will hold your network requests until the user is online again, and then process them when back online.

This article can explain this approach in more detail than I could here:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/12/background-sync

NOTE: this was written in 2015, and things have progressed a lot on this front. Service Workers aren't available yet in iOS, but they are expected to be supported within the next couple or years.